# PHP Composer (errno 2)

Tags: php, symfony1, composer-php, ezpublish

I wanted to create new ez publish 5 project using composer.phar but it fails

this is the result:

```
    $ ./composer.phar create-project  ezsystems/ezpublish5-standard 
    Installing ezsystems/ezpublish5-standard (dev-master 83d2466bbce3848ffc5b2c15e8bb5926fcf339b4)
      - Installing ezsystems/ezpublish5-standard (dev-master master)
        Cloning master

    Created project in /var/www/ezpublish5/ezpublish5-standard



     [ErrorException]                              
      chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)
```

Have you any idea how to fix it ?

thanx

Comment: Does your user have write rights to the currect directory?

Comment: Hi. Actually we didn't test it at the moment. But thanks for the flag, I'll post an aswer as soon as I'm able to test/debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You have to set the directory rights to 777.
I've written a little Hello-World-Tutorial for a complete eZ Publish 5 installation, for maybe upcoming problems.
http://www.ymc.ch/en/hands-on-ez-publish-5-installation-hello-world